# My ISP is rewriting google.com's DNS entry. how can I circumvent?

Tags: security, dns, privacy, ipconfig

I am in Thailand, and my ISP is ToT, and I am using Windows.

When I do a nslookup for google.com, I get the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

> set querytype-soa
> google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2404:6800:4001:805::1007
          118.174.25.178
          118.174.25.172
          118.174.25.163
          118.174.25.187
          118.174.25.183
          118.174.25.152
          118.174.25.177
          118.174.25.157
          118.174.25.168
          118.174.25.162
          118.174.25.182
          118.174.25.153
          118.174.25.158
          118.174.25.173
          118.174.25.148
          118.174.25.167
```

I see that **these IP addresses belong to my ISP**:  http://118.174.25.177.ipaddress.com/#ipinfo

A look at my IPConfig shows that my DNS servers are set to Google (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) and the University of Washington (128.95.120.1)

```
C:\Windows\System32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : jasons-work
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 14-DA-E9-E9-8C-9A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::90fd:63af:fa41:c4%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.10.15(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, March 3, 2014 10:53:28 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, March 23, 2014 12:07:51 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 253025001
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-80-FE-47-14-DA-E9-E9-8C-9A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
                                       128.95.120.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9F166031-E04C-443A-9EF0-66CFA35C6943}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:475:993a:49cb:1d76(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::475:993a:49cb:1d76%14(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

So my ISP is somehow rewriting my DNS result for google.com?  While some may think this is mallicious, I think it's probably just their incompetence.  (my requests to anything *.google.com return back network timeouts)

I don't have any custom software from my ISP installed, and I do have current antivirus up-to-date.

**How can I circumvent this rewriting of my DNS entries?**

I disabled IPv6 in my ethernet adapter, that had no impact. (i did ipconfig flushdns/renew afterwards)

**EDIT:**
In the whois registrant data for http://118.174.25.177.ipaddress.com/#ipinfo , I see the text "IP Assignment for Google Caching Systems".  So indeed it seems to confirm my ISP trying to cache google and screwing up.  The question of how to circumvent this still stands.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just not driving nslookup correctly.  Firstly, `set querytype-soa` should have given you an error.  If you really meant `set querytype=soa`, then you would be asking for Start Of Authority records and not Address records, so you definitely would not have gotten the response you show.

That said, the answer you got looks right for the part of the world you are in (Thailand).  Google has web-farms spread all over the world to handle the load.  There are even several in different parts of the United States.

Comment: i know that google uses it's own cdn network, but I'd assume that they would show whois ownership by google, not by my ISP.   

i'll do another test with the fixes you suggest.

Comment: ahhh, it gets even better.    i see my ISP is blocking DNS queries to other DNS servers, other than google (and I presume the ISP's own dns server, which i don't know the address).

maybe they have some agreement with google and are having technical dificulties.   anyway, seems DnsCrypt is still the way to go.

Comment: @JasonS, Why do you say "DnsCrypt is still the way to go" and what do you mean by that?

Comment: My ISP blocked using 3rd party DNS servers.  using DnsCrypt let me circumvent that.    However over the months that I used it,  I have noticed that DnsCrypt has it's own downtime outages, so beware.   I have since moved out of Thailand so I no longer need to use DnsCrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP has a peering agreement with Google. While it IPs are owned by and inside your ISPs network, the servers are Google's.

https://peering.google.com/about/ggc.html

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [DnsCrypt](http://dnscrypt.org/) and [the gui interface for it](https://github.com/Noxwizard/dnscrypt-winclient), and that solves my problem.

I'll leave the question open for if anyone else has a better, less invasive solution.